# Asker of a question should receive a notification if a bounty is placed on it by someone else

Tags: feature-request, bounties, notifications

I've [asked a question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/426810/changing-the-default-power-button-action-to-disconnect-in-a-remote-desktop-sessi) over a year ago and didn't quite get a satisfactory answer so it's been sitting there for a while.  I'm not very active on superuser so I'm not there all the time, I'll only check back if I ever get a notification that leads me there (e.g., comments, answers to questions, notifications, etc.).  I'm mainly active (to a degree) on stackoverfow and a couple other sites.

I recently [received an answer](https://superuser.com/a/632361) and got the usual notification so I went over to check it out.  To my surprise, I just noticed that my question has a bounty on it and has been there [since yesterday](https://superuser.com/posts/426810/revisions).  Had I known about it, I might have updated the question or left a comment regarding the status.  But alas, there was no notification or other indicator that there has been activity.  For virtually all  publicly visible post activities on the question itself, the asker receives notifications (exceptions: tweets, community bumps, and so on)... why not for bounties?

**Can a notification be sent out to the asker if a bounty is placed on their question by someone else?**

Comment: How did I miss that one...